# Receiving Error 415 : Unsupported media type when sending GET request with a REST API

Tags: python, httprequest, urllib2, exact-online

I've created some python code to communicate with Exact Online and want to send GET aswell as POST requests by using python with urllib2.

Now when i try to send a simple GET request including headers like 'Accept : application/json', which works when I tried it in a test application(SOAP-UI)

My python code is as followed :

```
import urllib2, urllib, json, requests, base64

data = urllib.urlencode({
})
request = urllib2.Request(
url="https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/"+divis+"/salesorder/SalesOrderLines?access_token=" + access,
data=data)

base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user,password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json+xml")
request.add_header("Accept", "application/json+xml")

request= urllib2.urlopen(request)
print request_open
response = request_open.read()
print response
```

Which results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101   5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 70, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 45, in retrieve_tokens
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type
```

I have tried this with both Content-Type and Accept aswell as both without the other. And all gave the same 415 response.
When i tried using only

```
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

or

```
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml")
```

I got the following response :

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I think this might be the cause of all this.

Anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Maybe worth mentioning that when i tested this with another application, the response had `Content-Type: application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8`

Comment: You should check the response payload. It might have more details on the error. Also, you should use python-requests instead of urllib2.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some web servers require you to send a `User-Agent` header in order to to work.

Try appending this:

```
request.add_header("User-Agent", "what u like")
```